# Definition of a Lubin Tate group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $L$ be a $p$-adic number field, $\mathcal{O}_L$ its ring of integers, $\pi$ a uniformizer of $L$ and $q$ the cardinality of its residue field.

Let $\varphi(t)\in \mathcal{O}_L[[t]]$ be a Frobenius power series for $\pi$, meaning that 
$$
\varphi(t)=\pi t+t^2(\ldots)
$$
such that $\varphi(t) \ \text{mod } \pi=t^q$.
I am familiar with the definition of a Lubin-Tate formal group law $F_{\varphi}(X,Y)\in \mathcal{O}_{L}[[X,Y]]$ for $\varphi$ from [these](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT310.pdf) notes.

The most well-known example is when $L=\mathbb{Q}_{p}, \pi=p$ and $\varphi=(1+t)^p-1$, then $F_{\varphi}$ becomes $\mathbb{G}_{m}=X+Y+XY$.

> I see though that many papers talk instead about *Lubin-Tate groups* instead of formal group laws and seem to call the above the above example as the *multiplicative group*. My question is what is the definition of a Lubin-Tate group then?

My guess is the following:

Using $F_{\varphi}$ one can define a group structure $(\mathcal{O}_{L},+_{F_{\varphi}})$, where
$$
x+_{F_{\varphi}}y:=F_{\varphi}(x,y)
$$
which can be checked to be a group from the axioms of a formal group law. Is this what the papers mean?

Comment: Yes you're right, the LT formal group laws are the ones induced by $\varphi$ satifying the conditions you've written out, this is stated clearly in the notes you're using on page 21 "The Ff ’s are the Lubin-Tate formal group laws. They are exactly the formal group
laws that admit an endomorphism reducing mod m to the Frobenius T → T q and
whose derivative at the origin is a prime element of K."